# TestStack/White dos not return any window of an application

Tags: c#, white-framework

I want know can i use [TestStack](https://github.com/TestStack/White) to doing an automate process on an application. so i wrote a simple code to count all windows of the target application.

**First** i tested it on a sample application (**WinForm (.net)**) and it **worked well** (Return 1 as Forms Count).

**Second** i tested it on **my target application** but it **dos not return any window** (Return 0 as Forms Count).

**My Code under the Button:**

```
TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Launch(@"C:\target.exe");

var windows = application.GetWindows();

foreach (var window in windows)
{
    MessageBox.Show(window.Title);
}
```

....................................[image]

**Additional info:**

- When i click on the Button, it can lunch my target application
  successfully.
- I did not know my application programming technology, i guess it is
  c++ and QT but maybe it is different!
- I watched `application` variable. Result is:

[image]

**Questions:**

- Which reasons can cause this problem?
- Should i switch to another way else TestStack to do automate proccess on this kind of application (for example use low level windows APIs and messages or....)?
- I'm a bigginer in TestStack, have i any mistake?
- What are your suggestions???

Thanks...

---

**EDIT 1**

- The target Application window ClassName: "Qt5QWindowIcon"   (i used SpyUI to get this)

Comment: I notice that it also seems to think that the target application has exited (HasExited is true).

Comment: @mikez is it possible when i run it, it changes its process with a new process and i lost it?

Comment: @mikez i found the problem and solve it base on you notic, i wrote an answer, very thank....

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem base on [@Mikez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517852/mike-z) notice in the comments.

**Reason of the problem was >>**

When i run the target application it changes itself process with a new process and i lost it?

**Solution:**
Now i changed my code to this and it works well ;)

```
 var myFirstTargetApp =TestStack.White.Application.Launch(@"c:\target.exe");
 myFirstTargetApp.Process.WaitForExit();

 TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("target");
  var windows = application.GetWindows();

  MessageBox.Show(windows.Count.ToString());  // << now my messagebox show:  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
TestStack.White.Application application = TestStack.White.Application.AttachOrLaunch("target");
```

Saves some lines of code.